# How can I pivot a collection of keys and arrays in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary

Let's say I had a collection of key of strings to decimals, like this:

```
{ "Alfred", [1, 2] }
{ "Batman", [1, 2, 3] }
```

How can I invert this relationship easily in C# to where the collection would be:

```
{ 1, ["Alfred", "Batman"] }
{ 2, ["Alfred", "Batman"] }
{ 3, ["Batman" ] }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
var d = new Dictionary<string,int[]>{
    {"Alfred", new[] {1,2}}
,   {"Batman", new[] {1,2,3}}
};
var res = d
    .SelectMany(p=>p.Value.Select(v => new {p.Key, Value = v}))
    .GroupBy(p => p.Value)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(v => v.Key).ToArray());
foreach (var p in res)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = ({1})", p.Key, string.Join(", ", p.Value));
```

This code produces this output ([ideone link](http://ideone.com/e378P)):

```
1 = (Alfred, Batman)
2 = (Alfred, Batman)
3 = (Batman)
```

Note the difference between `g => g.Key` and `g => g.Select(v => v.Key)`: the former selects the key of the *group*, while the later selects the key of the *original dictionary*.